# Display custom field in product (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to display custom field on product page.

I made field (Advanced Custom Fields) and add a rule to display in selected category on Posts. It works, I placed there a simple text and would display in product page. In editor I edit template and pasted the code:

```
<?php the_field( 'my_info' ); ?>
```

Unfortunately nothing appears.

I try also something like this:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=195&posts_per_page=1');
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( get_field('my_info') ): ?>

<?php the_field('my_info'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile;
?>
```

After this code field display, but there is a problem with loading other page sections.

What I make wrong?

Comment: The reason is that [query_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) alters the main loop.  It's recommended that you make a new instance of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) instead. Or you *could* just call `wp_reset_query();` after you are done (after your `endwhile`),  (It is considered bad style to alter the main loop back and forth, but it works if you're in a hurry.)

Comment: @ippi ok it works with wp_reset_query(); but how I can do this using WP_Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `query_posts()` is used, you have to put `wp_reset_query();` after the `endwhile()`. Otherwise use WP_Query .

```
<?php

$query=WP_Query('cat=195&posts_per_page=1');
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php if( get_field('my_info') ): ?>

<?php the_field('my_info'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```